# How to make Background of Google Custom Search Engine (Transparent)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

By default the background appears as white. Is it possible by any means to change it's background color to transparent..?

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '005519348941191855053:d0uziw7c2dq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

[image: Image of Google CSE(white background)]

Comment: So you want to make the container transparent?

Comment: Yes the outer white box.. transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the container transparent. You can always inspect the output of Google's script, and add customize it through CSS. You can target `.gsc-control-cse` with `!important`

```css
body {
  background:#f44336;
}
.gsc-control-cse {
  background:transparent !important; /* enforce this rule; do not allow override */
  border-color:transparent !important; /* border color */
}
```

```html
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '005519348941191855053:d0uziw7c2dq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: The search box isn't appearing for me..where do we have to insert the following code?                                                                                                             body {
  background:#f44336;
}
.gsc-control-cse {
  background:transparent !important; /* enforce this rule; do not allow override */
  border-color:transparent !important; /* border color */
}

Comment: Where doesn't it appear? In the snippet? You should put that code in head enclosed with `<style>` tags

Comment: Oh..yeah it works..sorry for the confusion..thank you..Adam A..keep up the good work.